# Flow of an Android App with ArrayList, ArrayAdapter and ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I am new in Android and I'm trying to develop a simple application with two layouts the first one contains a Button and a ListView. By pressing the button I am going to the second layout using an explicit intent. The second layout contains a Button and an EditText. Passing a string inside the EditText field and pressing the button I am transferring the string with the explicit intent in the first layout and then I have to add it in an ArrayList and pass it to the ListView through the Array Adapter.

My question is how to fix this application so it won't crush and if there is any other way to perform the flow.

This is my first activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListView extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
Button button;
android.widget.ListView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    //Getting the message from the FormView.class

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(FormView.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Getting the button's id

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second_button);

    //Passing the message to the ArrayList

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(message);

    //Passing the ArrayList in the ListView through the ArrayAdapter

    view = (android.widget.ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    view.setAdapter(aa);
}

private void addItem(String item) {
    if (item.length() > 0) {
        this.list.add(item);
        this.aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view, menu);
    return true;
}

public void formAppearance(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FormView.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

And this is my second Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import static com.freeshaman.shoppinglists.R.id.text_view;


public class FormView extends Activity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.freeshaman.ShoppingLists.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_view);

    // getting the intent from the first button

    getIntent();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.form_view, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendListName(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListView.class);
    EditText listName = (EditText) findViewById(text_view);
    String message = listName.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you have any problem in that flow?

Comment: Yes, my application crushes.

Comment: can you put `logcat`